# Electron internal or external method to create own right click context menu - Windows

Tags: c#, c++, node.js, windows, electron

Hello Stack Community :)
I have an Electron project and was wondering if it is possible to add an own row to the windows right click context menu. As example here cmder does the same.

[right click context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEots.jpg)

Edit:From the comment below it worked with registry editor to create an own row. But it will only open when you make right click into an empty area of the folder window. But for my Electron project I need to make right click on a folder/file as example and then I need the path structure of the file/folder sended to the terminal and executed as echo example that I can match the path via stdout in node.js. Also an alternative way would be if the path structure gets saved in an external file .txt as example. Any ideas for this without c++, c#, .net experience? I´am only familiar with web languages. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Might be of some help: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: Yes this worked thank you :) But I got a new problem I will edit the question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you could use atoms implementation of this.

Basicaly you use the package `winreg` to register/unregister the information.

The registry entries and how Atom does this can be found in atoms win-shell.js file at https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/src/main-process/win-shell.js

- exports.fileHandler is the open with ... one (option 1)
- exports.fileContextMenu is option 2 for all files on your system
- exports.folderContextMenu is option 2 for all folders on your system
- exports.folderBackgroundContextMenu is option 2 when you right-click inside a folder not on any specific file.

Depending on the context you then need to parse the arguments etc. normally this would be the filepath(s).

Comment: Thank you !! This looks very complex but should be what I´ve looking for. I will try it later this day and give feedback :)

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response but my CPU get defect. I don´t understand how to use this kind of codes :( import Registry from 'winreg' &
import Path from 'path' and other stuff is really new to me. Can you give me please a simple windows 10 example code for exports.fileHandler how to use and install? It´s not important that it runs from the electron process. I can also work with normal node.js files.